# How does the youtube algorithm to choose movie image works?

Tags: algorithm, youtube

IF you go to youtube, you'll see on the side alot of suggested movies. All movies has an image taken from one shot of the movie inside.
It is easy to see those images are not random (either an action scene or the one second there is a naked girl etc).
How is it being done?

Comment: You can analyse a video's content for differences between frames to detect cuts and fast scenes, an you can analyse an individual frame for the amount of detail in it (e.g. by computing the variation of the gradient or so), so you can try and pick a high-detail frame from within a slow cut surrounded by fast cuts, or some sort of heuristic like that...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is chosen by the uploader. When you upload a video, you get to set the frame that others will see. That frame, I presume, is stored in a database and voila.

Answer (score 1):

I actually tested this.  I had a video where I held a still frame all the way through the last half of a video.  The YT algorithm picked out a frame before the held frame for its #3 thumbnail image.  I repeated the same experiment, except that 3/4 of the way through I slid an element in the image by about 50 pixels over about 20 frames. The YT algorithm picked up the frame immediately before the move as its #3 thumbnail image.